# Preg_replace. Регулярное выражение пропускает первое значение

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Уважаемые знатоки!
Стояла задача заменить все точки (.) на многоточие (...) только в том случае, если точка не стоит в конце сокращений «г.»,«рис.» и «табл.».
Прошу подсказать, почему, при отработке preg_replace все нужные точки меняются как надо кроме самой первой?

```
$str = "Тестовый текст. Уважаемый г. Георгий, спасибо. Смотрите на рисунок и рис. 1. А также на табл. №2, Антон.<br>";
echo $str . "<br>";
$str2 = preg_replace('/(?<![г|рис|табл])\./i', '...', $str);
echo $str2 . "<br>";
```

Результат:

Тестовый текст. Уважаемый г. Георгий, спасибо. Смотрите на рисунок и рис. 1. А также на табл. №2, Антон.

Тестовый текст. Уважаемый г. Георгий, спасибо... Смотрите на рисунок и рис. 1... А также на табл. №2, Антон...

Comment: А с какого перепуга скобки квадратные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед первой точкой в тексте буква `т`, а так как в блоке предварительного просмотра вместо подмаски вы указали символьный класс, это совпадение на "засчитывается".

Используйте подмаску, удалите квадратные скобки, и желательно добавить границу слова `\b` перед каждым исключением:

```
$str = "Тестовый текст. Уважаемый г. Георгий, спасибо. Смотрите на рисунок и рис. 1. А также на табл. №2, Антон.";
$str2 = preg_replace('/(?<!\bг|\bрис|\bтабл)\./ui', '...', $str);
echo $str2;
// = Тестовый текст... Уважаемый г. Георгий, спасибо... Смотрите на рисунок и рис. 1... А также на табл. №2, Антон...
```

См. [демо онлайн](https://3v4l.org/VBmbu).